# C# как заставить Class Library использовать свой App.config

Tags: c#, settings

Имеется консольное приложение, которое через рефлексию инстанцирует класс (с определенным интерфейсом) из проекта `Class Library`.

Подразумевается, что проект `Class Library` будет использовать свой конфиг, но этого не происходит, еcли используется конфиг, то только консольного приложения.

Как сделать так, чтобы `Class Library` мог использовать свой `App.config`?

Comment: можно попробовать затолкать его в ресурсы и в библиотеке саму разбираться

Comment: @Grundy а через стандартный `ConfigurationManager` нельзя сделать?

Comment: можно, если будешь знать путь к этом конфигу: [Метод ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration (ConfigurationFileMap)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.openmappedmachineconfiguration(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Grundy чет я не догоняю

Comment: Поразмыслите ещё над архитектурой приложения. Стандартное решение заключается в том, чтобы хранить настройки в главном конфигурационном файле. `App.config` у **Class library** даже не создаётся по умолчанию: он там не нужен.

Comment: @MarkShevchenko у меня несколько ClassLibrary, можно конечно попробовать хранить все в одном файле...

Comment: @tCode Именно так всё и предполагается в .NET: настройки разных библиотек хранятся вместе. Именно поэтому и возникла проблема с конфигурацией: вам приходится что-то специально делать, чтобы разнести настройки, а если ничего не делать, то они все будут браться из одного файла. Так может быть как раз и проверить, почему вы хотите их разнести. Они действительно друг другу мешают?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Здесь 2 варианта:

1. Принудительно ссылаться на кастомный xml, как например это делает
   NLog с его NLog.config.
2. Использовать App(Web).config приложения, для
   чего можно использовать ConfigurationManager + (ConfigurationSection
   || appSettings).

Все остальное мне кажется вариантом велосипеда...

p.s. Для .Net Standard вариант "добычи" конфигурации сильно изменился...

Comment: спасибо за совет, помогло мне это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14812008